# IIS configuration URL mapping physical path

Tags: iis

Assuming URL:
`https://a.com/2.0.0.0/article/10.1/zh-CN/a.json`, the physical path I want to map to is `c:/program/2.0/a.json`,
and URL:
`https://a.com/2.1.0.0/blog/11/zh-CN/b.json`, the physical path to which I want to map is `c:/program/2.1/b.json`, and map according to the above rules.

If it is Nginx or Apache, it can be configured very well. Nginx is:

```
location ~ ^/(\d\d?\.\d\d?).+/(.+\.json)$ {
    try_files $uri /program/$1/$2;
}
```

Apache can be:

```
AliasMatch ^/(\d\d?\.\d\d?).+/(.+\.json)$  C:/program/$1/$2
<Directory "C:/program">
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Does anyone know how to configure IIS? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIS does not support such file system level mapping. You have to set up a valid site, so that short URLs like `https://a.com/2.0/a.json` and `https://a.com/2.1.b.json` become accessible, and then set up reverse proxy rules to enable the long URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I resloved the problem in a similar way.

Comment: Then you can post your own answer and accept it.